# How to change order of shipping address in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, admin, database

I want to change the order of **shipping address** like "name" , "last name" , "address" how will i do it in magento 2 admin panel.

Comment: There's no way to do it with admin configurations, you have to create a custom module/template and change some xml. You want to change it in guest checkout, in customer panel or both?

Comment: i just want to change it from admin view , how can i do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly this can't be done from admin view.

You need to create a module, [here you can find how](https://inchoo.net/magento-2/how-to-create-a-basic-module-in-magento-2/).

In that module you need to create a plugin for the LayoutProcessor. In there you can change the order of fields by using the following code.

```
 /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function aroundProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        array $jsLayout
    )
    {
        $jsLayoutResult = $proceed($jsLayout);

        if ($this->getQuote()->isVirtual()) {
            return $jsLayoutResult;
        }

        &$jsLayoutResult['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['telephone']['sortOrder'] = 122;

        return $jsLayoutResult;
    }
```

Hope this helps.